# How to return an ID for the row that has MIN/MAX value within a group?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, percona

```
SELECT
    MAX(`client_id`) `client_id`
FROM
    `phrases`
WHERE
    `language_id` = 1 AND
    `client_id` = 1 OR
    `client_id` IS NULL
GROUP BY
    `language_phrase_id`
```

How do I get the `id` for the row that holds `` MAX(`client_id`) `` value?

I need this in the context of derived table, e.g.

```
SELECT
    `p2`.`phrase`
FROM
    (SELECT `language_phrase_id`, MAX(`client_id`) `client_id` FROM `phrases` WHERE `language_id` = 1 AND `client_id` = 1 OR `client_id` IS NULL GROUP BY `language_phrase_id`) `p1`
INNER JOIN
    `phrases` `p2`
ON
    `p2`.`language_id` = 1 AND
    `p1`.`language_phrase_id` = `p2`.`language_phrase_id` AND
    `p1`.`client_id` = `p2`.`client_id`;
```

Comment: Per group as in above or just the max, period?

Comment: Do you really want to do `language_id = 1 AND client_id = 1 OR client_id` IS NULL` instead of `language_id = 1 AND (client_id = 1 OR client_id` IS NULL)`?

Comment: Here is the context, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fd79/1.

Comment: Is `id` different from `language_phrase_id`?

Comment: I don't quite understand... you want the max client_id where client_id is 1 or null?

Comment: Do not use `MAX`, add `ORDER BY id` and use `LINIT 1`.

Comment: p.s someone suggested to use `HAVING`, which sounds like a valid suggestion, except for that this column may contain NULL data, in which case it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit of trouble understanding the requirements, but this *seems* to be what you're looking for.
Not the most beautiful SQL and I'm sure it can be simplified, but a starting point;

```
SELECT p1.id, p1.phrase
FROM phrases p1
LEFT JOIN `phrases` p2
  ON p1.language_id=p2.language_id
 AND p1.language_phrase_id=p2.language_phrase_id
 AND p1.client_id IS NULL and p2.client_id = 1
WHERE p2.id IS NULL AND p1.language_id=1 
  AND (p1.client_id=1 or p1.client_id IS NULL)
GROUP BY p1.language_phrase_id
```

[An SQLfiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b819e/9).

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions to find the max for each group and then a `where` clause to select the row with the maximum:

```
select p.*
from (SELECT p.*, max(client_id) partition by (language_phrase_id) as maxci
      from phrases p
      WHERE (`language_id` = 1 AND `client_id`= 1) or
            `client_id` IS NULL
     ) p
where client_id = maxci
```

I also added parentheses to clarify your `where` statement.  When mixing `and` and `or`, I always use parentheses to avoid possible confusion and mistakes.

Now that you've added the `mysql` tag to your statement, this won't work.  So, here is a MySQL-specific solution:

```
select language_phrase_id,
       substring_index(group_concat(id order by client_id desc), ',', 1) as max_id
from phrases
group by phrases p
```

Note that this if `id` will get converted to a character string in this process.  If it has a different type, you can convert it back.